# lightning-input value is blank after hide/unhide

Tags: lightning-web-components

I noticed when you hide a section of the html file and then unhide it, the values in the section disappear. For example, when New Account is selected below, we fill in the Organization Name. If we then click Existing Account and then click New Account back again, the Organization Name is blank.

```
<template if:true={newAccount}>
     <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                <lightning-input required data-id="orgName" name="Name" label="Organization Name" ></lightning-input>
       </div>
</template>
<template if:true={existingAccount}>
     <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                <lightning-input required name="AccountName" label="Account Name"></lightning-input>
       </div>
 </template>
```

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be expected. You're literally removing the element from the DOM and then replacing it, so the value is reinitialized. You should store the value in your controller if you want the value to persist:

```
<lightning-input-field ... onchange={saveState} value={record.AccountName} />
```

...

```
record = { };
saveState(event) {
  this.record[event.target.fieldName] = event.target.value;
}
```